# Yahoo Contact API

Tags: php, javascript, yahoo

I am working on a simple email importer script. From what posts on this site have said, the ones that are for sale are either dodgy, or not worth the money spent, and as I know PHP and JS I thought this can't be hard, after all I have worked with Twitter API, and Facebook API.

However I seem to ran into a little bump in the road.

You see I am using Yahoo's very own script Yahoo.inc - http://developer.yahoo.com/social/sdk/php/

And all is going well as possible. However when I try to get the contacts I seem not to be able to. Now I have in the API settings for my app, ask for read request for contacts so I know it not that issue.

Here is my code I am using

```
$contacts = $user->getContacts();
```

However it seems not work work, it's like I am missing something. What is the correct way to get emails from the getContacts function Yahoo offers?

Comment: Any luck with this? It's driving me insane http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30919089/yahoo-php-sdk-getcontacts-intermittently-works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of the getContacts(), you can use a yql query for that:

```
$session = YahooSession::requireSession(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_APP_ID);   
$query = sprintf("select * from social.contacts where guid=me;");  
$response = $session->query($query); 


/**** printing the contact emails starts ****/
if(isset($response)){

   foreach($response->query->results->contact as $id){

       foreach($id->fields as $subid){

               if( $subid->type == 'email' )
               echo $subid->value."<br />";
       }
   }
}
/**** printing the contact emails ends ****/
```

Comment: I will try this - and let you know

Answer (score 1):

Looking at github you can see that the [yahoo-yos-php](https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-php) package is deprecated. it will be replaced by the [yahoo-yos-php5](https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-php5) package. Perhaps you should download that and try using it instead.

BTW, yahoo-yos-php uses a YOS API call ([doc](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/contacts-resource.html#contacts_resource-uris)) to fetch the data while yahoo-yos-php5 uses YQL queries.
So the end result of using the new package is the same as @mithunsatheesh solution only packaged in a yahoo distribution.

Here is a [link](https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-php5/blob/d4fb242d378c83beb573c79a6b35c55b02bfdc81/lib/Yahoo/YahooOAuthApplication.class.php) to the class, and the function itself:

```
public function getContacts($guid = null, $offset = 0, $limit = 10)
{
  if($guid == null && !is_null($this->token))
  {
    $guid = $this->token->yahoo_guid;
  }

  $rsp = $this->yql(sprintf('SELECT * FROM social.contacts(%s,%s) WHERE guid="%s"', $offset, $limit, $guid));

  return isset($rsp->query->results) ? $rsp->query->results : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Search this method `getContacts()` from yahoo api file (i.e Yahoo.inc), and increase the limit to 500. Initially it would be 10.