# Yahoo php sdk getContacts() intermittently works

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, yahoo, yahoo-api

I'm using the [Yahoo! Social SDK](https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-php5) to allow a user to authorize and then get a list of their contacts. I've setup the app to allow for the contact data to be read and this is verified when authenticating.

[image]

The authentication works because I can the profile using `getProfile()` on every single page load. The `getContacts()` is the problem though as 95% of the time it returns false which is not correct.

Am I doing something wrong with the request tokens that means `getContacts()` doesn't have the correct permission to run successfully or do Yahoo have some sort of strange caching issue with this query? It's even harder with the distinct lack of documentation from them regarding their api and php, is there another new library I can use to achieve this? I know it's possible because I can use a working version on the "AirBnb Invite a friend" webpage.

*This is the code I'm using, it's written using CodeIgniter so that explains the syntax.*

```
public function yahoo() {

    $oauthapp = new YahooOAuthApplication(DEV_OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, DEV_OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, DEV_OAUTH_APP_ID, DEV_OAUTH_DOMAIN);

    if($this->session->userdata('yahoo_oauth_access_token')){

        $oauthapp->token = YahooOAuthAccessToken::from_string($this->session->userdata('yahoo_oauth_access_token'));

        $profile = $oauthapp->getProfile();
        $contacts = $oauthapp->getContacts(0, 1000);

        if($profile)
           print_r($profile);
        else
            echo "No profile / error";

        if($contacts)
           print_r($contacts);
        else
            echo "No contacts / error";

    }
    elseif(!$this->input->get()) {

        $request_token = $oauthapp->getRequestToken(DEV_OAUTH_DOMAIN);
        $this->session->set_userdata('request_token', json_encode($request_token));
        $redirect_url = $oauthapp->getAuthorizationUrl($request_token);

        redirect($redirect_url);
    }
    else {

        $request_token = json_decode($this->session->userdata('request_token'));
        $oauthapp->token = $oauthapp->getAccessToken($request_token, $this->input->get('oauth_verifier'));

        $this->session->set_userdata('yahoo_oauth_access_token', $oauthapp->token->to_string());

        redirect("/index/yahoo");
    }
}
```

Comment: Appears that you're trying to get contacts and the token stored in session probably expired. You should always check by expired token and request a new when this happens (or use `refresh_token`). Anyway, had you considered use external contact importers, like [OpenInviter](http://openinviter.com) or [CloudSponge](https://www.cloudsponge.com/integrations/php)?

Comment: But I'm only storing it for 5 minutes or so in testing and it only works for the first time, is there a long token in Yahoo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the issue after a long long search, almost certain there will be others with this same issue as it's got no error outputting.

The issue was Curl in the library exceeding the runtime of 10 seconds, if this happens it just timeouts and the script ends. There were errors in my error_log but nothing on screen.

If you increase the timeouts on line 65 and 66 in `YahooCurl.class.php` then this fixes the issue.

```
  /**
   * Fetches an HTTP resource
   *
   * @param string $url    The request url
   * @param string $params The request parameters
   * @param string $header The request http headers
   * @param string $method The request HTTP method (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD)
   * @param string $post   The request body
   *
   * @return string Response body from the server
   */
  public static function fetch($url, $params, $headers = array(), $method = self::GET, $post = null, $options = array())
  {
    $options = array_merge(array(
      'timeout'         => '10',
      'connect_timeout' => '10',
      'compression'     => true,
      'debug'           => true,
      'log'             => sys_get_temp_dir().'/curl_debug.log',
    ), $options);
```